# How to stop date("i") function resetting after 59 seconds in PHP

Tags: php, date, unix, timestamp

My code below works out how much time has passed (as a unix time stamp) from a certain start time, up to the current time.

It then converts the unix time stamp into minutes using the `date("i")` function

This works fine, however when it reaches past 59 minutes, it then resets back to 0, instead of continuing on to 60 minutes.. 100 minutes.. 1000 minutes and so on.

Is there a way to make `date("i")` continue counting in minutes?

```
$difference = (time() - $supportrequest->startTime);
echo (int)date("i", $difference);
```

Comment: `$difference / 60` done.

Comment: @JonStirling  If I change my echo statement to say `echo (int)date("i", $difference / 60);` it changes the output to 0, when prior to your suggestion of using `/60` the output was 52. Am I still doing something wrong?

Comment: I'm suggesting not using date at all. Just `echo ($difference / 60) . ' minutes';`. Since `$difference` is the difference in seconds, and there are 60 seconds in a minute.

Comment: This worked! I would accept this as the answer, only since it is a comment it won't let me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you read the function documentation, it says that the parameter `i` returns a value between 00 and 59, which means that it CANNOT return a value over 59. That's why it resets.

If you want to confirm it yourself, here's the official documentation. It's worth a read: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

To sum up an answer to your question; No, there is no way to make `date("i")`continue counting in minutes.